# How to call data from webservices in this how to get (subcategoriescount) value

Tags: javascript

This is my Code:

```
{"subcategories":[],"subcategoriescount":"0","catname":"Gloves","weight":"","products":[{ 
                            "product_id":"2584",}]
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: where do you want to get this code i.e subcategoriescount, in javascript or jquery or in php. Is your webservice is returning this data in json format ?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data was not working, so I added the missing last curly bracket and removed the comma after "2584", then it worked (PHP is very sensitive to JSON syntax). Once you got the JSON data from the webservice, you get "subcategoriescount" this way:

```
<?php

$my_data = '{"subcategories":[],"subcategoriescount":"0","catname":"Gloves","weight":"","products":[{"product_id":"2584"}]}';

$my_object = json_decode( $my_data ); // CONVERT FROM JSON TO OBJECT.

echo "Subcategoriescount value is = " .
     $my_object->{"subcategoriescount"};  // WILL DISPLAY "0".

?>
```

To test previous code, create a text file, give it any name with PHP extension, copy-paste the code, open your browser and run `localhost/anyname.php` . To asure it is working, go to the JSON string and replace the value for "subcategoriescount", from "0" to "5" (or any other), you should see something like this on screen:

```
Subcategoriescount value is = 5
```